# Read whole std::ifstream to heap

Tags: c++

I cannot work out why this isn't working.  From what I can tell, it doesn't appear to be reading the whole image file...  Though I cannot tell.  I basically have some raw image that I'd like to read onto the heap.

```
unsigned char* ReadImageFromFile(const char* FILENAME, unsigned int SIZE_BYTES)
{
    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*) malloc(SIZE_BYTES);

    std::ifstream image(FILENAME);
    image.read((char*) data, SIZE_BYTES);
    image.close();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Stop mixing C with C++ and it will work.

Comment: First off, if you're using c++ please don't use malloc(), we have new for that. That being said, check return value of image.read - does it return SIZE_BYTES or less? If you're reading raw data, you might want to open file in binary mode.

Comment: @Alex1985, no, we have better primitives than `new`. We have containers, we have smart pointers - `new` is almost never an answer.

Comment: Please consider not using malloc, or C style casts. They are a recipe for trouble. Also consider reading into a std::vector.

Comment: @Griwes, indeed.. I was looking for nearest C++ equivalent of malloc(). Smart pointer would indeed be better

Comment: Although it's not a proper way to use `malloc()` in C++, but still it should work. Why do you guys say the problem is `malloc`? :-/

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ can help you find out what is going on (gcount, internal state flags)

Comment: @Javid More likely, the problem is that you're not opening the file in binary mode.  If you're under Windows (and most other non-Unix systems), reading a binary file in text mode will result in missing data: all 0x0D will be removed, and the first 0x1A will terminate the input.

Comment: How big is the file compared to SIZE_BYTES?

Comment: This needs to run on a microcontroller...  I want it to be fast.  I don't want to use any containers like smart pointers or the stl.

Comment: @user968243, a smart point like `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr` adds **zero** overhead compared to error-prone hand-rolled memory management. On the other hand, `fstream` adds a number of virtual calls that are not present if you use `fopen` and `fread`, so if running on a microcontroller really should affect your choice of coding style, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) open the file in binary mode

2) don't return a raw pointer that needs to be freed

```
std::string readImageFromFile(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream image(filename, std::ios::binary);
    std::ostringstream data;
    data << image.rdbuf();
    return data.str();
}
```

Or if your prefer to write error-prone code (seems to be popular with the embedded crowd) you could do it this way:

```
char* readImageFromFile(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream image(filename, std::ios::binary);
    std::ostrstream data;
    data << image.rdbuf();
    data.freeze();
    return data.str();
}
```

Of course there's a good reason strstreams are deprecated.

Comment: I need to return a raw ptr.  I don't want an std::string.  I probably should've mentioned this code is running on a microprocessor.

Comment: OK, answer updated to avoid `std::string`, if you prefer it that way

Comment: It certainly is popular with the embedded crowd!  To be honest, I actually need it that way, because I'm using opencv and I need to swat the data pointer of a cv::Mat with the pointer I get back from this file.

Comment: You can use std::string very well with opencv or similar. With pointers alone, you will make it wrong. Here for example, how would you tell how big is returned? It is binary, there is no \0 character on the end. use std::string or std::vector. then use std::string().c_str() or &std::vector[0] to pass pointer to C-only functions. And it will just free itself at end of function.

Answer (score 3):

Try `std::ifstream image(FILENAME, std::ios_base::binary);` (note the second argument to `ifstream` constructor).